# Dynamic menu options in an ASPX page rendered by C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASPX DropDownList whose ListItems must be populated dynamically from values in Dynamics CRM.

Changing the visibility of page elements when certain input tags are triggered isn't the issue - populating an asp:DropDownList with dynamic asp:ListItems is.

Specifically, when the page is loaded, the ListItems that are visible in the drop down MUST be populated on the fly from an up-to-date list of entities from our CRM which changes every hour.

As far as I know, the ASPX itself can not contain logic, that's for the C#, but I don't know how to populate the ListItems this way.

I did come across this guy's solution:

http://aspsnippets.com/articles/creating-dynamic-dropdownlist-controls-in-asp.net.aspx

But during my attempts to compile it to see how it functions, I received an error regarding multiple form tags.

Any ideas?

---

Specifically, I have the following ASPX:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="location" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="updateOther">
<asp:ListItem>North</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>South</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>West</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList id="other" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>Option 1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Option 2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Option 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I need it so that the available options in "other" are changed/updated with up-to-date values from our CRM depending on which location is chosen in the "location" dropdown. Again - the values in "other" are going to be populated from an on-the-fly query of our CRM database performed in the "updateOther" method.

Comment: Some small sample of code could make your question more concrete. Side note: "ASPX itself can not contain logic" is not true, whether it is good practice or not is personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand your problem very well, but if i were you i would put the other dropdownlist in a usercontrol, pass the query data as json parameter to it by jquery, and load it upon each request
something like below

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "default.aspx/LoadUserControl",
            data: "{query: '" + $("#location").val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                //Clear the div before load   
                $("#SomeDIVinYourPage").before(r.d);
            }
        });
```

in your codebehind

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string LoadUserControl(string query)
    {
        using (Page page = new Page())
        {
            UserControl userControl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl("OtherUserControl.ascx");

            page.Controls.Add(userControl);
            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                page.Controls.Add(userControl);
                HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```